# how to find out which uvs we need to flip

Tags: uv, normals

in Maya, we can see flipped UVs in red and correct ones in blue. So is there any way to find out which one is the unflipped/wrong UV in blender??

Comment: Hello :). As with many things in Blender, there's an addon for that: [Flipped UVs Selector](https://blenderartists.org/t/addon-flipped-uvs-selector/668111?u=jachymmichal)

Comment: thank you so much :)) it helped

Comment: Flipped as in the loops go clockwise?

Answer (score 0):

In the latest versions the [Magic UV Addon](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/uv/magic_uv.html) is already included but needs to be activated.

You can automatically select all flipped faces and flip them:

[image: Flip UV commands]